# Is it safe to add EC2 public IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django + Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Django app as a single instance Elastic Beanstalk environment without Elastic Load Balancer. The setup is Nginx + Gunicorn + Django. SSL is enabled for Nginx server.

I have added the host assigned by elastic beanstalk  (....elasticbeanstalk.com) to ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings file, and the app is accessible.

But some operations are failing and there are a lot of Invalid HTTP_HOST_HEADER errors in the log file. The header in majority of these errors are the Public IP of the EC2 instance.

Is it safe to add the EC2 Public IP to the allowed hosts ?